# why are there no pictures or experiments on solid ozone?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

wikipedia states that solid ozone is violet black in colur and so is my textbook, but when you search up for solid ozones, there are no pictures or experiments done in youtube. Was the colour or the compound actually made or was it theoritically proven somehow that the colour was violet-black.
Was just curious to know

Comment: They cannot physically capture images of solid ozone due to difficulty working with it and not to mention supercold temperature. But studies has been made. See: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/j100339a004; https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/17718620/. Regarding ozonides, see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WhcfBLop5gM

Comment: Solid ozone was certainly made, so researchers *looked* at it. I seriously doubt any dudes specialising in putting videos on YT did it, though. It's not easy and solid ozone is *explosive*.

Comment: Liquid O3 is already highly explosive and even gas could explode if given the chance - it's not something to be trifled with.

Comment: https://docslib.org/doc/7696119/the-history-of-ozone-iv-the-isolation-of-pure-ozone-and-determination-of-its-physical-properties-1

Comment: This text^ says solid O3 was photographed, but a photo in a paper and one googlable are two different things.

Comment: @Mithoron when I bring up your last reference they do not show the photograph (which I would have screenshit onto my device and then uploaded with appropriate sourcing). But photographs of the liquud are available and well document a violet coloration.

Comment: @OscarLanzi It's only a mention that one team made a color photo.

Answer (score 1):

The color of *liquid* ozone is documented in [sciencemadness.org](https://www.sciencemadness.org/smwiki/index.php/Ozone):

[image]

[Liquid diatomic oxygen, for comparison:](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Liquid_oxygen_in_a_beaker_(cropped_and_retouched).jpg#mw-jump-to-license)

[image]

The color difference is similar to what we see between aquo and ammine complexes of copper, and for fundamentally the same reason: the deeper-colored form requires more energy to photoexcite an electron into an antibonding orbital. In the case of ozone versus diatomic oxygen, the increased energy comes from the delocalized pi bonding in the triatomic molecule, which raises the energy of the electron-accepting antibonding orbital.

Comment: Well, the question asked for solid ozone and not liquid ozone :)

Comment: @NilayGhosh But ozone can explode on fast cooling, so it's always something ;)